# Programmatically send PayPal payment Objective C

Tags: objective-c, rest, curl, paypal, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to send a payment programmatically via PayPal but it's not working. Please advise, thanks.

My code is below, and below that is PayPal's cURL example.

```
-(void)createPayment {
    NSString *shortDescription = @"test description";
    NSDecimalNumber *paymentDecimal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", [Global sharedInstance].currentOrder.itemPrice]];
    NSString *sku = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DBAR-%i", [Global sharedInstance].currentOrder.orderNumber];

    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Global sharedInstance].currentOrder.boozeBrand];
    PayPalItem *item = [PayPalItem itemWithName:name withQuantity:[Global sharedInstance].currentOrder.itemQuantity withPrice:paymentDecimal withCurrency:@"USD" withSku:sku];
    float priceFloat = [item.price floatValue];
    float totalFloat = priceFloat * item.quantity;
    NSDecimalNumber *total = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", totalFloat]];

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.amount = total;
    payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
    payment.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    payment.items = nil;  
    payment.paymentDetails = nil; 

    if (!payment.processable) {NSLog(@"Payment not processable.");}

    NSString *token = [Global sharedInstance].accessToken;
    NSString *bearerToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", token];

    NSDictionary *redirectDict = @{@"return_url":@"http://www.testurl.com",
                                   @"cancel_url":@"http://www.testurl.com"};
    NSDictionary *payerDict = @{@"payment_method":@"paypal"};

    NSMutableDictionary *amountMutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [amountMutableDict setObject:total forKey:@"total"];
    [amountMutableDict setObject:@"USD" forKey:@"currency"];
    NSDictionary *amountDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:amountMutableDict];

    NSMutableDictionary *transactionsMutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [transactionsMutableDict setObject:amountDict forKey:@"amount"];
    [transactionsMutableDict setObject:shortDescription forKey:@"description"];
    NSDictionary *transactionsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:transactionsMutableDict];

    NSMutableArray *transactionsMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [transactionsMutableArray addObject:transactionsDict];
    NSArray *transactionsArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:transactionsMutableArray];

    NSMutableDictionary *dataMutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dataMutableDict setObject:@"sale" forKey:@"intent"];
    [dataMutableDict setObject:redirectDict forKey:@"redirect_urls"];
    [dataMutableDict setObject:payerDict forKey:@"payer"];
    [dataMutableDict setObject:transactionsArray forKey:@"transactions"];
    NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dataMutableDict];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:bearerToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"intent=sale&redirect_urls=%@&payer=%@", redirectDict, payerDict];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long [postData length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:postData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"\nPurchase Response:\n\n%@", response.description);
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authorization Failed" message:@"Your payment did not go through." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }];    

    [task resume];

}
```

PayPal's cURL example from their docs:

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
  -v \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer accessToken' \
  -d '{
    "intent":"sale",
    "redirect_urls":{
      "return_url":"http://return_URL_here",
      "cancel_url":"http://cancel_URL_here"
    },
    "payer":{
      "payment_method":"paypal"
    },
    "transactions":[
      {
        "amount":{
          "total":"7.47",
          "currency":"USD"
        },
        "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
      }
    ]
  }'
```

Here is my response from PayPal via my above NSLog statement:

Purchase Response:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1512732d0> { URL: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment } { status code: 400, headers {
    "CORRELATION-ID" = c0b729159d0c7;
    Connection = "close, close";
    "Content-Language" = "en_US";
    "Content-Length" = 200;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Mon, 04 Apr 2016 19:48:20 GMT";
    "PROXY_SERVER_INFO" = "host=slcsbplatformapiserv3001.slc.paypal.com;threadId=675";
    "Paypal-Debug-Id" = "c0b729159d0c7, c0b729159d0c7";
    Server = Apache;
    "Set-Cookie" = "X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dplatformapiserv%26TIME%3D80020055; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
    Vary = Authorization;
} }
```

Someone PLEASE tell me why the payment isn't going through. I'm not getting an error (or it wouldn't print the response), I know the token is good because I have to log in to PayPal each time I use the app, and I can't figure it out. Thanks!

C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing the NSURlResponse Description, you should print the JSON data to console to give you a better idea. Modify your code to look like this:

```
NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:postData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
     NSError* jsonError;
     NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions 
                                                   error:&jsonError];
     NSLog(@"\nPurchase Response:\n\n%@", json); //You will have to edit this to use the actual error object returned from the curl request.
} else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authorization Failed" message:@"Your payment did not go through." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}];
```

Once you have done this, you should have a much better idea of what's going wrong.

Update:

I see now more of what's going on. Your request is indeed malformed: Your post, and post data values are incorrect; you're sending a string value (like you'd send via a url) instead of json (these lines below)

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"intent=sale&redirect_urls=%@&payer=%@", redirectDict, payerDict];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
```

Instead replace those two lines with this:

```
NSError *jsonError;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataDict options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks @jrobe - should have done this originally before I posted the question. Just as I thought there's something wrong with the JSON request:

Comment: Purchase Response:

{
    "debug_id" = fbcc3a0134a8;
    "information_link" = "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST";
    message = "The request JSON is not well formed.";
    name = "MALFORMED_REQUEST";
}

Comment: My friend, you are a saint. Thanks again. @jrobe

Comment: Not a problem, my pleasure!